# Interfacing an LM2903B output to a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, comparator, interface

I would like to connect the output of a LM2903B comparator to my controller to read the output signal. Both the comparator supply voltage +13V and the controller supply 3.3V are referenced to the same ground.

Do I need to place Schmitt trigger or a series resistor to the output of the comparator? What things do I need to consider to connect the output to a controller GPIO?  The inverting input is a DC voltage which varies from 0V to +11V.

[image]

Comment: Isn't R13's purpose exactly the hysteresis you are asking about when you ask about the placement of a Schmitt trigger?

Comment: Whether you need a Schmitt trigger or not depends entirely on what you plan to do with the signal coming out of the comparator.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, but all i want to know wheather i need anything in between comparator output and controller GPIO. I just want to read the output after power up condition.

Comment: Seeing that the maximum voltage at the 5SOUT pin is about 3 V, and that's probably within the acceptable input range of your microcontroller: no, this should be fine. As said, you already built hysteresis, so more Schmitt triggering should not be necessary, unless you can't live with the slow "low->high" transition (around 160 µs) due to limited charging speed of C10. But then again, if that mattered, you'd probably reduce C10.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for confirmation. Do i need any high impedance between comparator output to controller input to limit the current ??

Comment: @EmbeddedEnthusiast I will not repeat what I have already written in the previous comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Marcus Muller pointed out, R13 is providing hysteresis, so the output will already be a very sharp, emphatic high or low.

The pull-up resistor R14 to +3.3V is what determines the "high" output potential. That would be exactly +3.3V were it not for R13, which will shift that a little, slightly towards whatever the potential at its other end is. As long as you keep R13 very large compared to R14, this won't be an issue.

Do not use C10 as you have it here. You risk damaging the output transistor of the comparator, and you also risk reducing the output rise rate to something too slow for the MCU input, resulting in spurious readings of that pin during transition.

You have hysteresis, I see no need to filter or slew-rate limit the comparator output, so drop C10.

Comment: Or, move C10 across VCC and GND of U2.

Comment: @simon Fitch Thanks for the answer. Do i need to place any series reistance to the output to limit the current ?? Is there any impact to GPIO or 3.3V due to +13V supply variations??

Comment: @EmbeddedEnthusiast The open-collector of the comparator can only pull the signal to ground, so the comparator on its own can't cause any problems for the MCU (if the grounds are common, as you say). The only other sources of current are R13 or R14, which already limit current, in the event of the MCU input potential being clamped by the MCU's input protection diodes. It's fine.